# How can I create and distribute my own private blockchains in a scalable way?

Tags: private-blockchains

I would like to experiment with blockchains in a controlled environment for fun and/or development purposes. Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: This is what regtest is for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes there is:
https://github.com/coinclone/cloner

You can mine genesis blocks, configure common settings for nodes on your network and ship them easily using this opensource project.